# Magento 1.7. error after attempting restore to backup

Tags: magento-1.7

A frustrating mishap. 
Did a backup in anticipation of testing a module install. Didn't like the module install so restored to backup.

**After restore cannot login to admin.** Front and back both have error as follows below. Reviewed the files by FTP. No Lib folder, no JS folder, no Media folder. Other folders are there and the contents appear to be there, but since there are hundreds of files, I've no way to know. Can I just re-install the missing folders?

> Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   /homepages/9/d464072087/htdocs/shop/app/Mage.php on line 50
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for
>   inclusion
>   (include_path='/homepages/9/d464072087/htdocs/shop/app/code/local:/homepages/9/d464072087/htdocs/shop/app/code/community:/homepages/9/d464072087/htdocs/shop/app/code/core:/homepages/9/d464072087/htdocs/shop/lib:.:/usr/lib/php6')
>   in /homepages/9/d464072087/htdocs/shop/app/Mage.php on line 50
>
> Warning: include(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   /homepages/9/d464072087/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
>   on line 68
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/homepages/9/d464072087/htdocs/shop/app/code/local:/homepages/9/d464072087/htdocs/shop/app/code/community:/homepages/9/d464072087/htdocs/shop/app/code/core:/homepages/9/d464072087/htdocs/shop/lib:.:/usr/lib/php6')
>   in
>   /homepages/9/d464072087/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
>   on line 68
>
> ```
> Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in
> /homepages/9/d464072087/htdocs/shop/app/Mage.php on line 53
> ```

Thanks to all in advance,
dbc

Answer (score 1):

The file `Varien/Autoload.php` is located in the **lib** directory, so if you say you don't have it the site can't load. I would indeed copy the missing files from the installation file and see if the site will work again. You should also check your installed extensions to see if they placed something in the missing directories.

Comment: I just uploaded lib and js folders. I can see the directories, but nothing works. I did a previous backup on 8/8/13. Is there any way I can manually restore to that date? Where is this backup located?

Comment: worst case, i have to reinstall. can I download my attributes, categories, etc from somewhere first?

Comment: The backups are stored in var/backups/, if that doesn't work you could do a reinstall but use the current database so you still have all your settings. Also check if all files have the correct permissions, maybe the directories can't be created because there are not enough rights to create them from the webinterface. If you can restore the backup from the commandline you can see what errors it gives.

Comment: I see the backup in var/backups from 8/8. how do I re-deploy it without being able to go through the Magento dashboard interface?

Comment: Also, where to find the database to back up before reinstall?